How to make a module available from profile.ps1 with Import-Module
I have a profile.ps1 in my Documents/WindowsPowerShell folder which runs when I start pwsh that loads all commands but not a Import-Module -Global ./Modules/test/test.psm1 file. If I type the command in the shell the module is available.
The complete command
Import-Module .\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\DisplaySettings/DisplaySettings.psm1
The module is dotnet-7.0 c# file.
EDIT: got this solved by checking  $Profile|Format-List * -Force (thanks Mathias!) and putting the module in the CurrentUserAllHosts\..\Modules folder.

Windows PowerShell runs on .NET Framework, it won't be able to load .NET 7 assemblies. If you're using PowerShell 7, make sure you're editing the right profile script (check the $PROFILE variable)

@MathiasR.Jessen copying the psm1 file in the CurrentUserAllHosts Module folder auto loads and compiles the script (in my case) as soon as one of the cmdlets are called. But maybe I misunderstand you.
